# PyCharm Tools | Run setup.py is missing

Tags: pycharm

I wanna run Run setup.py Task sdist. But it is missed in menu Tools | Run setup.py, what can i do?

screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGd7C.png

Comment: To make this action visible some file should be opened (to determine project), this project should have `setup.py` and Python interpreter specified

Comment: and in case, you run it once and it disappears. restart pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Python interpreter isn't set properly in PyCharm